# Which experiments of harmonic generation at low frequencies preceded Franken's SHG?

Tags: experimental-physics, history, harmonics

In *The Principles of Nonlinear Optics* by Shen, he says that the generation of harmonics at low frequencies were long-known before Franken did SHG in the optical range.

> Franken's idea was simple. Harmonic generation of electro­magnetic waves at low frequencies had been known for a long time. Harmonic generation  of optical waves follows the same  principle and  should  also  be observable.

Which are those experiments ?

Answer (score 2):

It is done all the time in acoustics, ask any musician!

However Shen probably was referring to harmonic generation in radio frequencies; with radio is is called a [frequency multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_multiplier).  The [heterodyne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterodyne) technique was invented in 1901.

The  [Kerr effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_effect) was first found about 1876. The first footnote in this article provides some historical background: altering the polarization of light with strong magnetic fields. This is non-linear optics, but there is no change to the frequency.

Comment: Rectification on crystals seems to have been discovered in 1874...